# Remove duplicates without using an aggregate function

Tags: sql, oracle, duplicates

So, I am trying to export the race of each student from our SIS, and I am having trouble because if a student is multiracial then there would be more than one row for each student. Usually, I would use some aggregate function to remove those duplicates, but I am placing it within a plugin and the system won't accept aggregate functions. What I am trying to do is take all of the kids who are multiracial and place them in one row with them being named Multiracial. I have to do this without an aggregate function. Here is an example of the code with an aggregate function.

```
select DISTINCT
   
        Student_number,
            case 
                when min(sr.racecd) = max(sr.racecd) then min(sr.racecd) else 'Two or more races' 
End as races
from students
Group by...
```

The output would look like this:

```
Student_Number   races
5234             White
4343             Two or more races
4323             Asian....
```

Is there a way to do this without an aggregate function, or am I at a roadblock?

Answer (score 0):

Create a view and get the simplistic plugin query it instead of the table.

For example:

```
create view simple_student as -- and then your query below
select DISTINCT
  Student_number,
  case when min(sr.racecd) = max(sr.racecd) 
       then min(sr.racecd)
       else 'Two or more races' 
  end as races
from students
group by ...
```

Then the plugin can export data from `simple_student` instead of `student`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use analytic functions:

```sql
SELECT student_number,
       CASE
       WHEN num_races = 1
       THEN racecd
       ELSE 'Two or more races'
       END as races
FROM   (
  SELECT student_number,
         racecd,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY student_number ORDER BY racecd) AS rn,
         COUNT(DISTINCT racecd) OVER (PARTITION BY student_number) AS num_races
  FROM   students
)
WHERE  rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use left join for every race replacing nulls in STUDENT_NUMBER with 0 and then do the addition of all of them. If the result is equal to the actual student number then it is just one race and you can get it with Coalesce(). Here is the code:

```sql
WITH
    students (STUDENT_NUMBER, STUDENT_NAME, RACE) AS
        (
            Select 5234, 'Jack', 'White' From Dual Union All
            Select 4343, 'John', 'Black' From Dual Union All
            Select 4343, 'John', 'White' From Dual Union All
            Select 4323, 'Lee',  'Asian' From Dual 
        )

Select  DISTINCT s.STUDENT_NUMBER, 
        CASE WHEN Nvl(w.STUDENT_NUMBER, 0) + Nvl(b.STUDENT_NUMBER, 0) + Nvl(a.STUDENT_NUMBER, 0) = s.STUDENT_NUMBER
             THEN  COALESCE(w.RACE, b.RACE, a.RACE)
        ELSE 'Two or more races'
        END "RACES"
From students s
Left Join ( Select STUDENT_NUMBER, RACE 
            From students
            Where RACE = 'White' ) w ON(w.STUDENT_NUMBER = s.STUDENT_NUMBER)
Left Join ( Select STUDENT_NUMBER, RACE 
            From students
            Where RACE = 'Black' ) b ON(b.STUDENT_NUMBER = s.STUDENT_NUMBER)
Left Join ( Select STUDENT_NUMBER, RACE 
            From students
            Where RACE = 'Asian' ) a ON(a.STUDENT_NUMBER = s.STUDENT_NUMBER)

R e s u l t :
STUDENT_NUMBER RACES           
-------------- -----------------
          4323 Asian             
          4343 Two or more races 
          5234 White
```

No aggregations, no groupings, no analytic functions ... just left joins, Nvl()-s and a bit of math.

Comment: I never seen a join used in that way.. very interesting